# how do you destructure a list in scala

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```
val host:String = Play.configuration.getString("auth.ldap.directory.host").get
val port:java.lang.Integer = Play.configuration.getString("auth.ldap.directory.port").get.toInt
val userDNFormat:String = Play.configuration.getString("auth.ldap.userDNFormat").get
```

to which I need to add a dozen more config options, so I was hoping to refactor it to something like:

```
val params = Seq("auth.ldap.directory.host", "auth.ldap.directory.port", "auth.ldap.userDNFormat")
params.map(Play.configuration.getString) match {
  case host~port~userDNFormat => foo(host, port, userDNFormat)
}
```

I made that code up. What is the proper syntax to do this? On the map/match line I get this error, which I do not understand:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : (String, Option[Set[String]]) => Option[String]
required: java.lang.String => ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in order to match on a sequence, you can write

```
case Seq(host, port, userDNFormat) => foo(host, port, userDNFormat)
```